# How to push an associative array inside an new array

Tags: php, associative-array

Hello I am trying to push associative arrays inside an array. But I can't figure out how to do so. All I managed to do is to push the index without its associated value. Can you guys help me figure this out?

Here's my code :

```
<?php
$mainshelf = array(
               shelf1=> array('apple'=>5, 'banana'=>6, 'lemon'=>7, 'apricot'=>8, 'mango' =>9),
               shelf2=> array('salad'=>13, 'tomato'=>12, 'carrot'=>2, 'zuchini'=>15, 'potato' =>20),
               shelf3=> array('veal'=>20, 'mutton'=>22, 'chicken'=>19, 'pork'=>25, 'fish' =>17)
               );

 ?>

<?php
session_start();
include 'data.php';

//Generate options in each select
function select($shelf){
        foreach($shelf as $key=>$value){
            echo "<option>$key</option>";
        }
    }



// Creating the shopping cart tab
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart']=[];
}

//Storing items in shopping cart
function listitems($selectshelf){
    if(!empty($selectshelf)){
        array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$selectshelf);
    }

}


// Print out the cart's content
function cartcontent() {
    if(!empty($_SESSION['cart']))
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$value){
            echo "<p>$value</p>";
        }

}


   ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="php.css">
         </head>
         <body>
         <div id="container_shelf">
           <div class="shelf">
            <h2>Fruits</h2>
        <form action="php1.php" method="post">
            <select name="fruits">Fruits
                <?php select($mainshelf[shelf1])?>
                <?php listitems($_POST['fruits'])?>
            </select><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">

        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="shelf">
        <h2>Vegetables</h2>
        <form action="php1.php" method="post">
            <select name="vegetables">Vegetables
                <?php select($mainshelf[shelf2])?>
                <?php listitems($_POST['vegetables'])?>
            </select><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="shelf">
        <h2>Meat</h2>
        <form action="php1.php" method="post">
            <select name="meat">Meat
                <?php select($mainshelf[shelf3])?>
                <?php listitems($_POST['meat'])?>
            </select><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
        </form>
    </div>




</div>

<div id='shopping_cart'>
        <h2>Shopping cart</h2>
        <?php cartcontent(); echo"<br>"?>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can't push a key/value pair of an associative array. Instead you can `$SESSION['cart'][$selectShelf] = $mainshelf[ $selectShelf ]`. Btw, `$mainshelf[shelf1]` is invalid syntax - it should be `$mainshelf['shelf1']`.

Comment: Where in my code should I put this?

Comment: You'd do that instead of the `array_push` (inside `listitems`) - but you'd need to add a `global $mainshelf;`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to "push" something into an array is this:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $selectshelf;
```

It will put the content of `$selectshelf` in a new element at the end of the array, no matter what its value is.

Comment: I did what you suggested but,when I use print_r the value associated to each item doesn't show: Array ( [0] => apple [1] => carrot [2] => lemon [3] => lemon [4] => carrot [5] => carrot [6] => carrot [7] => apple [8] => apple [9] => apple [10] => apple )

Comment: I actually need the associated value for each item. I plan to sum them up inside a "total" variable.

Comment: In that case your `$_POST['...']` aren't arrays but just strings. Try `[ $_POST['vegetables'] => $mainshelf[ shelf3 ][ $_POST['vegetables'] ]`. as the argument for `listitems`. 

(side note: you might want to rethink your data structure for cleaner ways to access data within the structure and for saving you lots of trouble in the future)

Comment: I wrote this but I guess there's something wrong because the line is underlined in red :<?php listitems($_POST['meat']=>$mainshelf['shelf3'][$_POST['meat']])?>

Comment: `listitems( [ $_POST['meat']=>$mainshelf['shelf3'][$_POST['meat']] ] )`

Comment: Ok thanks. Now I want to print the name of the item (veal, tomato, etc.) and its associated value (20, 22, etc.). When I do the following only 'Array appears:function cartcontent() {
  if(!empty($_SESSION['cart']))
   foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$value){
    echo "<p>$value</p>";
   }
   
 }

Comment: `$value == [ 'name' => 123 ]` so use `foreach($value as $name => $amount)` to access your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using arrays as values

```
$shelf = array(
    'book1' => array('title' => 'XYZ', 'pages' => 200),
    'book2' => array('title' => 'ABC', 'pages' => 100)
);
```